# K8s 'calico' pods not starting: "Failed to create default IPv4 IP pool: 10.244.0.0/16 error=resource does not exist:"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, calico

I'm new to Kubernetes, so please bear with me. I deployed K8s on Ubuntu 20.04 and am having issues with the 'kalico' pods and also the coreDNS pods:

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS       AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-56cdb7c587-85qrr   0/1     Pending                 0              4m24s
kube-system   calico-node-kjmmh                          0/1     Error                   5              168m
kube-system   canal-btw4r                                0/2     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   5 (48s ago)    4m24s
kube-system   coredns-5fcc94c66-6wptx                    0/1     Pending                 0              149m
kube-system   coredns-5fcc94c66-lkxbp                    0/1     Pending                 0              149m
kube-system   coredns-6d4b75cb6d-l68p2                   0/1     Pending                 0              154m
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                            1/1     Running                 1 (158m ago)   3h39m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master                  1/1     Running                 1 (158m ago)   3h39m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master         1/1     Running                 1 (158m ago)   3h39m
kube-system   kube-proxy-lndkt                           1/1     Running                 1 (158m ago)   3h39m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master                  1/1     Running                 1 (158m ago)   3h39m
```

Checking the calico pod logs I see this:

```
root@k8s-master:~# kubectl logs -n kube-system calico-node-kjmmh
Defaulted container "calico-node" out of: calico-node, upgrade-ipam (init), install-cni (init), flexvol-driver (init)
2022-06-21 23:12:45.486 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 299: Early log level set to info
2022-06-21 23:12:45.486 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 315: Using NODENAME environment for node name
2022-06-21 23:12:45.487 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 327: Determined node name: k8s-master
2022-06-21 23:12:45.487 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 359: Checking datastore connection
2022-06-21 23:12:45.504 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 383: Datastore connection verified
2022-06-21 23:12:45.504 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 104: Datastore is ready
2022-06-21 23:12:45.505 [INFO][8] startup/customresource.go 101: Error getting resource Key=GlobalFelixConfig(name=CalicoVersion) Name="calicoversion" Resource="GlobalFelixConfigs" error=the server could not find the requested resource (get GlobalFelixConfigs.crd.projectcalico.org calicoversion)
2022-06-21 23:12:45.512 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 664: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface ens192: 192.168.3.71/24
2022-06-21 23:12:45.512 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 727: No AS number configured on node resource, using global value
2022-06-21 23:12:45.512 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 201: Setting NetworkUnavailable to False
2022-06-21 23:12:45.522 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 772: found v4=10.244.0.0/16 in the kubeadm config map
2022-06-21 23:12:45.522 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 776: found v6= in the kubeadm config map
2022-06-21 23:12:45.523 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 616: CALICO_IPV4POOL_NAT_OUTGOING is true (defaulted) through environment variable
2022-06-21 23:12:45.523 [INFO][8] startup/startup.go 928: Ensure default IPv4 pool is created. IPIP mode: Always, VXLAN mode: Never
2022-06-21 23:12:45.525 [ERROR][8] startup/startup.go 934: Failed to create default IPv4 IP pool: 10.244.0.0/16 error=resource does not exist: FelixConfiguration(default) with error: the server could not find the requested resource (post FelixConfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org)
2022-06-21 23:12:45.525 [WARNING][8] startup/startup.go 1214: Terminating
Calico node failed to start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now: **I did not have a working CNI**

I had issues with flannel (and calico), so gave up on them and used Kube-Router instead: https://github.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md

`kubeadm reset`
`KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/master/daemonset/kubeadm-kuberouter.yaml`